# Working with Google Maps using Python 3

Tags: python, google-maps, python-3.x

I wish to create a program that when the address is entered, it will display the location using Google Maps. However, I do not know how to link the address with Google Maps as well as how to show the map using Python 3. My application will run on Windows platform.

Please suggest how should I start...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is the low-tech solution: just launch a browser window.

```
webbrowser.open("https://www.google.com/maps/place/"
                "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue Northwest, Washington, DC")
```